# How to get Java script variable from HTML using HttpClient

Tags: java, android, html

I need to get the js variable from `HTML`. I get html from server using `HttpCLient`, and try to search "src" in `stringBuilder`. 
I want to get  image  URL   shown on page.
Thml sting that i parsed.
How to get this variable?

> < img id="h5" src="8.jpg" border="0">

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 30 * 1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 30 * 1000);
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        httpGet.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        //Запрос
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStream instream = null;
        try {
            instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
        if ((contentEncoding != null) && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
            try {
                instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, "utf-8"), 8);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains("\" src"))
                {
                 sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }}
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            instream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String result = sb.toString();
        Log.i("Do id back", " ");
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        txtUrl.setText(result.toString());
        Log.i("on Post","   ");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not even a question mark in this post.

Comment: Have you managed to parse the lines containing `" src` yet? And if yes, where's your code so far?

Comment: I dont know how to get value of variable. I do not parsed this lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an HTML parser, e.g. [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).